# What do you call a person who is generous but on other's account

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What would you call a invited person who comes in a restricted party hosted by a fellow collegian and then invites most of the uninvited members in the college and apparently blatantly shows off his generosity and the party as if his own?

That is, he invites others to party and says "feel free to have food" (the food which is limited due to restriction on invitees) and moreover it appears to the uninvited people who come to the party that he is the host of the party.

Comment: Are you saying that this person *telephones* others and boasts, or actually *invites* others to the party?

Comment: Actually he invites others to the party and says "feel free to have food" (the  food which is limited due to restriction on invitees) and over the top it appears to the uninvited people who come to the party as if he is the host of the party. He is a shameless senior and hold good amount of power but still it is unethical as per my opinion.

Comment: 'Off the next invitation list.' But is this really a rant? There are many words and phrases that could be used in this situation, but I doubt there's a word defined as 'a person invited to a private party (hosted by a fellow collegian) who brings along most of the uninvited members in the college and then flagrantly shows off 'his generosity', implying the party is his own'.

Comment: A type of 'impostor'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no definition for the *exact* description you've provided, but this person's bad behavior can be aptly described by calling them a [usurper](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/usurper).

> **Usurper**
>   *noun*
>
> A person who takes a position of power or importance illegally or by force.
>       *e.g. ‘a usurper of the throne’*

For your context, I would call them a "party usurper".

Basically, their behavior boils down to this:

[image: Cartoon of someone appropriating another's invention]

[Image from Nedroid](https://nedroidcomics.tumblr.com/post/41879001445/the-internet)

Comment: While appreciating the irony, use of others' material does need to be acknowledged here. [The original is apparently by Nedroid](https://nedroidcomics.tumblr.com/post/41879001445/the-internet)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Fair point (also on the irony), will update for correctness.

Comment: I don't think 'usurper' would be what most people call this person. And there are very few relevant Google hits for "party usurper".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Does this person not supplant the actual host of the party? If not literally (openly calling themselves the host), then at least in practice (giving permissions that only the host is allowed to give)? I agree that 'usurper' tends to operate on a more official level than the OP's context, which is basically nothing more than a social faux-pas. But figurative usage should still apply. Calling someone a dictator does not always mean that you think they are a _literal_ head of state, for example.

Comment: 'What do you call a person' calls for an idiomatic answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Just because an idiomatic answer does not exist, does not mean the question is inherently impossible to be answered. My answer was posted in absence of an idiomatic answer, as I can't think of a single example that encapsulates the exact (very specific) meaning that OP is looking for.

Comment: Try not to answer then; ELU stands for English Language and _Usage_.